# Increase size of content property of a CSS class

Tags: html, css

I have content property set to dashed arrow "-->". But it appears very small. I want to increase its size in the `CSS` class itself. It is supposed to appear before each **stage** class element. The **stage** class element is present in a `inline-flex`.

```
.stage::before{
  content: '\21E2';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

Comment: have you tried font-size?

Comment: Use font-size like (font-size: 20px). It will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `font-size` property

```
.stage::before{
  content: '\21E2';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size:20px /*add according you*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You change it the same way you change any other text.

With the `font-size` CSS property.